# Как понять какая вызывается функция?

Tags: linux, node.js

Вот код в nodejs.

```
app.use(function(req,res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Не найдено');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(500);
    res.send('500 - Ошибка сервера');
});
```

Comment: Это код express.js. Но в чём вопрос я так и не понял

Comment: Есть две функции, они возвращают две ошибки. Как может вызваться ошибка 404 и как может вызваться ошибка 500, если функции просто написаны подряд.

Comment: Вам стоит начать читать с документации express.js, в частности как там устроена обработка ошибок

Comment: А нашел. Express может различить обработчики 404 и 500 по количеству аргументов, принимаемых их функциями обратного вызова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express может различить обработчики 404 и 500 по количеству аргументов, принимаемых их функциями обратного вызова.